# ACM ICPC -Number Theory

Tags: c++, algorithm, number-theory

I was practising ACM ICPC past problems http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1030

I am not able to solve this problem and have completely no idea how to do it in an efficient way within the 3 seconds time limit.
I think this problem is based on Number theory, but don't know exactly what to do.
Thanks!

Comment: No-one wants to follow a link to understand your question; please summarise the problem description here.

Comment: Well, An integer version of Gauss-Jordan seems appropiate. Maybe add some dynamic programming idiom, too.

Comment: I think Gauss for `N = 1000` will definitely exceed the 3 seconds.

Comment: This can be helpful: http://online-judge.uva.es/board/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2295

Answer (score 1):

Although transformed into vector problems, three-dimensional vectors and so many variables are somewhat tricky, so we can first reduce dimensionality and change the original equation into:
`A[1]* (s[1][2]-s[1][1], s[1][3]-s[1][1]) + a[2]* (s[2][2]- s[2][1], s[2][3]- s[2][1]) +.....+a[n]* (s[n][2]- s[n][1],..+a[n]*) = (())`.
The two-dimensional vector is regarded as the vector starting from the origin in the plane coordinate system. If there are only two vectors, because `a[i]` is a non negative number, so the angle must be `PI` when there are only two vectors. N vectors can satisfy the above equation if the angle between the two adjacent vectors is not greater than `PI`. The code is not long, but it needs a mathematical thinking T_T
Here is the correct code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int maxn=1000+5;
const double PI=acos(-1);
int main()
{
    int n;
    double A[maxn];
    while(scanf("%d",&n),n)
    {
        int s1,s2,s3;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d%d",&s1,&s2,&s3);
            A[i]=atan2(s2-s1,s3-s1);
        }
        sort(A,A+n);
        double tmp=0;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
            tmp=max(tmp,A[i]-A[i-1]);
        tmp=max(tmp,A[0]-A[n-1]+2*PI);
        if(tmp<=PI)
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe given:

```
(a1,b1,c1), (a2,b2,c2) ... (an,bn,cn)
```

You need to **decide** if there exists non-negative coefficients:

```
X = (x1,x2,...,xn)
```

such that

```
x1*a1 + x2*a2 + ... + xn*an == 
x1*b1 + x2*b2 + ... + xn*bn == 
x1*c1 + x2*c2 + ... + xn*cn
```

A little linear algebra is all it takes.

**Hint**: Try and construct an input with n == 4, such that all 4 xis are required to be positive to solve the problem (and it cannot be solved with just 3).  Is this possible?

Comment: That's not entirely right: you don't have to use all `a1, ..., an` - any subset is fine.

Comment: @IVlad: In that case the xi is 0

Comment: Oh, that's right. Could you detail the solving process a little please? I don't see an obvious way of doing it fast for n <= 1000.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos - Fatho:: I didn't understand one thing- Is answer yes if x1>0 && x2>0 ...&& Xn>0 and no if any of the (x1,x2,x3..xn)is negative?

Comment: @Jack: Ummm... a valid answer means that `(x1,x2,...,xn) >= (0,0,...,0)`.  Answer yes if and only if a valid answer exists.

Comment: Well fi9 ,any hint how to decide if there exists non-negative coefficients?Is any algorithm exists to solve such equations!

Comment: @Jack: Imagine that the vectors were 2D (and not 3D), how would you solve it then?

Comment: This isn't just a straightforward application of linear algebra as the nonnegative integers do not form a field, or even a ring for that matter.